# Aggregate sum doesn't work in Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I got a problem to sum the budget and the balances. This is the code to make a kendo grid with the datasource.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
           dataSource: vm.dataSource,
           schema: {
              model: {
                 fields: {
                    description: { type: "string" },
                    budget: { type: "number" },
                    balance1: { type: "number" },
                    balance2: { type: "number" },
                    balance3: { type: "number" },
                    balance4: { type: "number" },
                    balance5: { type: "number" },
                    balance6: { type: "number" },
                    balance7: { type: "number" }
                 }
              }
           },
           height: 430,
           group: {
              field: "description", aggregates: [
                { field: "budget", aggregate: "sum" },
                 { field: "balance1", aggregate: "sum" },
                 { field: "balance2", aggregate: "sum" },
                 { field: "balance3", aggregate: "sum" },
                 { field: "balance4", aggregate: "sum" },
                 { field: "balance5", aggregate: "sum" },
                 { field: "balance6", aggregate: "sum" },
                 { field: "balance7", aggregate: "sum" }
              ],
              aggregate: [{ field: "description", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "balance1", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "balance2", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "balance3", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "balance4", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "balance5", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "balance6", aggregate: "sum" },
                { field: "balance7", aggregate: "sum" }]
           },


           filterable: {
              mode: "row"
           },
           pageable: false,

           columns: [
           {
              field: "description",
              width: 150,
              title: "descriptions",
              footerTemplate: "Total (excl. BTW)",
              filterable: {
                 cell: {
                    operator: "contains"
                 }
              },
           }, {
              field: "balance1",
              width: 130,
              title: "balance1",
              aggregates: ["sum"],
              groupFooterTemplate: "Sum: #=sum#",                
              filterable: {
                 cell: {
                    operator: "gte"
                 }
              }
           }, {
              field: "budget",
              width: 130,
              title: "Budget",
              aggregates: ["sum"],
              groupFooterTemplate: "Sum: #=sum#",                
              filterable: {
                 cell: {
                    operator: "gte"
                 }
              }
           }]
        })
```

For this example I use two columns to sum up. When I use the groupFootertemplate tag it doesn't show the total of the budget or balance.

I used this source to sum up:
[link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it!

```
     aggregate: [{ field: "description", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance1", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance2", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance3", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance4", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance5", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance6", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance7", aggregate: "sum" }]
       },
```

This code must be inside the Datasource like this:

```
dataSource: {     aggregate: [{ field: "description", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance1", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance2", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance3", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance4", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance5", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance6", aggregate: "sum" },
            { field: "balance7", aggregate: "sum" }]
       },
```

}